# Alternate form of $e^{-2.6x}$.

Tags: calculus

How would I convert the equation $f(x)=3.5e^{-2.6x}$ to the form $f(x)=A\cdot B^x$. Is $A=3.5$ and $B=e^{-2.6}$?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you're right.